# Class not found phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following structure of my project:

```
.
├── Api
├── ClickHouse
├── Core
├── Database
├── Manage.php
├── Middlewares
├── Models
├── Modules
├── README.md
├── Serializers
├── Utils.php
├── app.yaml
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config.php
├── cron.yaml
├── dispatch.yaml
├── include.php
├── index.php
├── loc.config.php
├── phinx.php
├── phinx.yml
├── php.ini
├── phpunit.xml
├── scripts
├── static
├── tests
└── vendor
```

And I'm trying to run PHPUnit tests from the `/tests/` folder. And there's an error with `Class not found` (but class exists and it runs fine from the `index.php` file). My composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-json": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
        "robmorgan/phinx": "^0.11.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9",
        "google/recaptcha": "^1.2",
        "opis/closure": "^3.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "odan/phinx-migrations-generator": "^4.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "migration:create": "vendor/bin/phinx create",
        "migration:migrate": "vendor/bin/phinx migrate"
    }
}
```

Also my phpunit.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/8.5/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         executionOrder="depends,defects"
         forceCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true"
         verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Where did I go wrong?

*some text to update the question, can not update it due to the code is too large*

Oops, I have to add the code of the example test as a picture
[image: test example]
And this code fails with `Class UserModel not found`

Comment: Just to make sure - UserModel is in Models folder, with `namespace Models;` defined?

Comment: On a side note, use [this](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.5/assertions.html#assertinstanceof) to assert what you're trying to check in the image.

Comment: HI, I don't see any `autoload` entry in your `composer.json` maybe you forget it ?